# grails smart substring method - works even if ending index out of bounds

Tags: grails

I've got lots of 'description' properties in my domains.  These could get quite long.  I'd like to put the first n characters of the description into the toString() for the domain class.  Great.  But during execution, if the string is < n on a propertName.substring(0,n) - it blows a gasket - index out of range.

Q: how would I go about fixing this, most effectively?  Thinking of adding a domain class property method, or a string class method, smartSubString(start, end, ifNullOrEmpty) that would return the full lenght if its length is < end, and if it's empty or null, return what's specified in the 3rd optional param, with a default of empty string.

I would appreciate other suggestions and specifics of where to put this method, like what folder, and how to include it into grails.

Thanks!

Comment: Part of the functionality is a duplicate.  In order to have a different default result if the string is empty or null, one would need to implement something like below. The groovy take() method described in safe-string-slice does not have that feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String.metaClass.subStringWithDefault = {init, last, defaultVal = null ->
    delegate ? delegate[init..(delegate.size() > last ? last : -1)] : defaultVal
}

def string = 'This is a test String'

assert string.subStringWithDefault(0, 5, 'default') == 'This i'
assert string.subStringWithDefault(0, 50,'default') == 'This is a test String'
assert string.subStringWithDefault(7, 50,'default') == ' a test String'
assert string.subStringWithDefault(7, 50) == ' a test String'
assert string.subStringWithDefault(7, 10,'default') == ' a t'
assert ''.subStringWithDefault(0, 50,'default') == 'default'
```

I would put this utility in `src/groovy` as part of a `StringUtils` class and initiate in Bootstrap.

```
//src/groovy
class StringUtils {
    static initUtils(){
        smartSubString()
    }

    static smartSubString() {
        String.metaClass.subStringWithDefault = {init, last, defaultVal = null ->
            delegate ? delegate[init..(delegate.size() > last ? last : -1)] : 
                 defaultVal
        }
    }
}

//BootStrap
import static com.example.mypackage.StringUtils

def init = {
    initUtils()
}
```

Comment: Cool - Thanks. And where would I put the String.metaClass, so its in one place and accessible by all the domain classes?

Comment: Something likely shown above in the updated answer. @Twelve24

Comment: Please don't put it in utils, that's for codecs. It's oddly named but historically it was going to be a place for codecs and other minor artifact types that didn't merit their own grails-app subfolder. But none were added after codecs. Put utility classes in src/groovy or src/java

Comment: @BurtBeckwith How can I index your book in my mind and tip of the finger? I have to read it several times I guess. Thanks, updated my answer accordingly. I guess book's name could be "Power of Grails Habits".... :) (inspired by Power of Habits)

Answer (score 1):

I'd put a method like this in a utility class in src/groovy:

```
package com.foo.bar

class Utils {
   static String safeSubstring(String s, int maxLength) {
      s ? s[0..(Math.min(maxLength - 1, x.length() - 1))] : ''
   }
}
```

and call it in domain classes as

```
import com.foo.bar.Utils

...

String toString() {
   Utils.safeSubstring propertyName, 5
}
```